# I am retriving all the object using getGlobalDescribe how can i add that list to a picklist?

Tags: schema

```
public class dynamicSoqlController {

    public List<Schema.SObjectType> globalSchemaList = new List<Schema.SObjectType>();
    public List<Schema.SObjectType> getGlobalDescride()
    {
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalDescribeMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
        for(Schema.SObjectType gd : globalDescribeMap.values())
        {
            globalSchemaList.add(gd);
        } 
        return globalSchemaList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [SelectOption](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) objects:

```
public SelectOption[] getTypeOptions() {

    String[] types = new String[] {};
    for (SObjectType t : getGlobalDescride()) types.add(String.valueOf(t));
    types.sort();

    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {};
    for (String t : types) options.add(new SelectOption(t, t));
    return options;
}
```

that you use in Visualforce like this:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!type}" size="1">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!typeOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```